# With iOS Inter-App audio deprecated, what is the replacement?

Tags: ios, audio, avaudiosession, audiounit

With iOS Inter-App audio and AUGraph being deprecated (according to the [iOS 13 public beta release notes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/ios_ipados_release_notes/ios_ipados_13_1_beta_release_notes)), how does one expose the existence of an Audio Unit or custom AVAudioNode audio source to another audio destination app, and how does a destination app (recorder, player, and/or visualizer) get sent audio samples from the audio source app (synthesizer or on-screen keyboard)?